# How to increase number of devices on a mobile hotspot?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, mobile-hotspot

I set up a mobile hotspot. According to the admin panel, I can only allow up to 8 devices to connect to it.

How do I increase the maximum number of connected devices from 8 devices to 20 devices?

[image: Screenshot of mobile hotspot settings]

Answer (score 9):

If you add a `Dword` value named **`WifiMaxPeers`** to

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\icssvc\Settings`

it will change the upper limit in Mobile Hotspot, e.g. I changed it to decimal 10, and the Mobile Hotspot control panel showed "Devices connected: 0 of 10".

I have tested this with 10 connected clients concurrently.

I strongly suggest making the change with Mobile Hotspot turned off and rebooting for the changes to take effect.

The maximum value of this key appears to be decimal 128. Larger values prevent Mobile Hotspot from starting.

Comment: Thank you! It is working as expected. Nice finding! Here is Regedit file for limit of 32 devices:

Comment: ```Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\icssvc\Settings]

"WifiMaxPeers"=dword:00000020```

Comment: Did you see which service reads the value? Would like to restart the service perhaps instead of rebooting the whole machine...

Comment: I noticed that when I disconnected from wifi and reconnected, the new value was used

Comment: Doing this for 20 devices will appear 20 but will never let connect +10.... Any advise?

Comment: Works as expected. Just a reboot and everything is now okay. I have tried with 20 and it works

Comment: There is no such spot "icssvc" in Services. Windows Server 2019

Answer (score 1):

To.supplement the other answers:https://superuser.com/a/1620967/1777639
No need restart,
just run powershell or cmd, run commond

```
stop-service "icssvc"
get-service "icssvc" 
start-service "icssvc"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This would appear to be a supplement to one of the other answers that show how to increase the number of devices. In itself, it doesn't actually answer the question. Maybe preface your answer with "To.supplement the other answers" and/or link to the particular answer that you are addressing.